# More intuitive filtering of a single R Shiny datatable column using multiple strings

Tags: r, regex, filter, shiny, dt

I have an R Shiny app like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

# Example data
data <- data.frame(col1 = c("syncope", "fall", "dizziness", "headache", "back pain"),
                   col2 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))

# Shiny app
ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$mytable <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(data, filter = 'top',options = list(search = list(regex = TRUE)))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I was able to code it to this way to allow filtering with multiple conditions, thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25556358/filter-shiny-datatable-on-multiple-conditions).  However, Regex isn't really that intuitive.  Someone would have to enter **sync|dizz** to filter down to the rows that show ***sync**ope* and ***dizz**iness*.  Or **p[ae]** to filter on *back **pa**in* and *synco**pe***.

Is it possible to code things in such a way that you could separate 2 strings with a space, or with the word 'OR', to achieve this instead?  For instance, you could enter **sync dizz**, or maybe **sync OR dizz**.  This would be more intuitive for users.

Please note that I am referring to the search boxes that are above each column (blue arrow), not the general Search box that was referred to in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61346922/batch-searching-regex-in-shiny-dt-datatables-with-spaces-not-pipes) (red arrow).

[image]

Comment: Use the search builder extension, very good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an alternative approach to the excellent answer of @Stéphane Laurent that could be an option for you:

The only change to your code is to transform the column of interest to factor: `data$col1 <- as.factor(data$col1)`
The you will get a dropdown list, also typing and hitting enter for more entries is possible:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

# Example data
data <- data.frame(col1 = c("syncope", "fall", "dizziness", "headache", "back pain"),
                   col2 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))

data$col1 <- as.factor(data$col1)

# Shiny app
ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$mytable <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(data, filter = 'top',options = list(search = list(regex = TRUE)))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]